# Как записать аудио с микрофона и воспроизвести?

Tags: android, аудио, java

Как записать звук с микрофона в буфер и воспроизвести? И как записать его потом в файл с форматом flac?

Answer (score 1):

[Читайте документацию](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html) - всё описано и написано тысячу раз.

Comment: Я эту документацию уже тысячу раз читал. Меня интересует запись в буфер, а не в файл. Читайте внимательнее